# Does SDN4 allow multiple relationship of collection type to the same Entity?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

When I try to get different relationship type of collection object, the collection property will retrieve all the same entity type even if the relationship type if not the collection relationship type. Is it a bug ?

The entity Demo contains two fields which reference to User entity : user and users

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.RelationshipEntity;

@NodeEntity
public class Demo extends FormLog implements java.io.Serializable {


    private String name;


    @Relationship(type="MY_USER")
    private User user;

    @Relationship(type="DEMO_USERS")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public Demo(){}
    public Demo(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }




}
```

When I save the demo with 1 "MY_USER" and 2 "DEMO_USERS", it is fine.
But when I get find the Demo by group id, the "DEMO_USERS" return 3 users.

```
@Test
public void test_saveAndFindOne_save2KindsOfUser_NoConfliction(){

    Demo demo = new Demo();

    List<User> user = userService.findUserByNameLike("Hank");

    demo.setUser(user.get(0));

    demo.getUsers().add(user.get(1));
    demo.getUsers().add(user.get(2));

    demo.setName("Set Multiple");


    demo = demoRepository.save(demo);

    System.out.println("Users size =  "+ demo.getUsers().size());
    System.out.println("==========Get Demo from DB ==============");
    Demo db = demoRepository.findOne(demo.getId());
    System.out.println("Users size =  "+ db.getUsers().size());


}
```

The output

```
Users size =  2
==========Get Demo from DB ==============
Users size =  3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are running into: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/38

You should be able to work around this by annotating your `setUser` and `setUsers` methods with the appropriate `@Relationship`

If that does not help, please report an issue (or add onto the one above).

**Update**:
Confirmed that this is indeed the same issue as described in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/38

Until this issue is fixed, you'll need to make your objects navigable in both directions. In your example, `User` will need to have two references to `Demo` each annotated with the appropriate `@Relationship`

Comment: Hi Luanne, 
The Relationship type is different for the two kinds of User

Btw, I'm using noe4j-ogm-1.1.3

Comment: I think it is still the same issue, but I'll take a look at the one you've just logged and confirm

Comment: Confirmed that it is the same issue. Please see updated answer